# Scroll viewer contains listbox. vertical scroll bar issue on selecting bottom element in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have put list box in a scroll viewer.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="HostScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox x:Name = "listBox1">
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
  </ScrollViewer>
```

I can scroll through all list items but when I scroll down list box items and select bottom item of the list box then my vertical scroll bar goes to initial position.

Comment: try CanContentScroll="false" in the first line

Comment: Why do you have listbox wrapped in scrollviewer? Listbox Template already contains scrollviewer? Second, why have you modified ItemsPanel?

Comment: No. Still its not working. If I write CanContentScroll="False" then I am not able to scroll items using mouse scroll.

Comment: @Liero Because I don't want to restrict listbox's height. My list box's height would be equal to total height of its elements. I need to use that template to host my other user control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is just:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" />
```

the problem in your code with scrolling by mouse whell is that yo have two scrollviewers, actually: HostScrollViewer and the one in Listbox Template.

And why it scrolls to top, when you select item? Well, it's because when you set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` on the HostScrollViewer, and you select an item in listbox, the HostScrollViewerscrolls to ListBox not listboxitem. Just because ListBox has another scrollviewer.

the other option is to disable scrollviewer in the listbox:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="HostScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="False">
    <ListBox x:Name = "listBox1" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Disabled"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But the visual result will be the same

Comment: thanks its working :) but now I am not able to scroll with mouse scroll